# ADXL345BCCZ output problems in a high voltage, high magnetism environment

Tags: electromagnetism, high-voltage

I'm trying to find a fault in an ADXL345 being used in a very specific application where it is near both high voltage and high magnetism. Is it known to suffer in this application? The circuit was designed by someone much cleverer than me and the compiler license has long expired so I've no access to the software used. It's feeding data to an Atmeg324P and it is stable until the voltage and the resultant magnetism are applied and then sometimes you get chaos, though not always. I've tried swapping chips and it has made a difference on a couple of occasions, so has reflowing. I don't like the mounting but not much I can do there. The scope looks like the output dc bias just goes mad. I've tried getting the voltage, up to 400V off the board and I've tried to screen the chip but no one thing seems to give a reliable solution. Frankly, I'm baffled.

Comment: have you tested it away from magnetic fields and away from high voltages?

Comment: Hi. I have yeah, I arranged for a test board to be made and unfortunately it doesn't have the fault. I thought I'd found the problem but I hadn't. That was the point I gave up and asked on here. I now need to do it on my known faulty board.